# PageController can't be requested via XmlHttpRequest in Shopware 6

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, shopware, symfony-routing

I am trying to send a request to my custom `StorefrontController` on the latest Shopware `6.2.2` but I am getting the following error:

```
PageController can't be requested via XmlHttpRequest.
```

I am doing a regular `httpClient` request as such from a custom JS plugin :

```
export default class MyCustomPlugin extends Plugin {

  static options = {
      dataUrl: '', // comes from the twig as "path('frontend.path.to.route')"
      product: null,
      params: {},
      loadingIndicatorClass: 'is-loading',
      responseSelector: 'some-selector-class'

  }

  init () {
      // this.el.innerHTML = LoadingIndicator.getTemplate()
      this.httpClient = new HttpClient()
      const query = querystring.stringify(this.options.product)
      this.sendDataRequest(query)
  }

  /**
   * Add classes to add loading styling.
   * Prevents the user from clicking filter labels during filter request.
   */
  addLoadingIndicatorClass () {
      this.el.classList.add(this.options.loadingIndicatorClass)
  }

  /**
   * Remove loading styling classes.
   */
  removeLoadingIndicatorClass () {
      this.el.classList.remove(this.options.loadingIndicatorClass)
  }

  /**
   * Send request to get filtered product data.
   *
   * @param {String} filterParams - active filters as querystring
   */
  sendDataRequest (filterParams) {

      this.addLoadingIndicatorClass()

      this.httpClient.abort()
      this.httpClient.get(`${this.options.dataUrl}?${filterParams}`, (response) => {
          this.renderResponse(response)
          this.removeLoadingIndicatorClass()
      })
  }

  /**
   * Inject the HTML of the response to the element.
   *
   * @param {String} response - HTML response
   */
  renderResponse (response) {
      ElementReplaceHelper.replaceFromMarkup(response, this.options.responseSelector, false)
      window.PluginManager.initializePlugins()
  }
}
```

And here is my `StorefrontController` route:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/path/to_route", name="frontend.path.to.route", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function someAction(Request $request, Context $context): JsonResponse
```

Can anyone tell me why the request is not going? I want to send a simple AJAX request to my own controller in Shopware 6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with adding:

`defaults={"XmlHttpRequest"=true}` to your Route.

So after the changes you will have:

```
/**
* @Route("/path/to_route", name="frontend.path.to.route", methods={"GET"}, defaults={"XmlHttpRequest"=true})
*/
```

Also make sure that the scope is properly defined in the controller using the `@RouteScope` annotation. Since your code is a storefront JavaScript plugin, it should have the `storefront` scope defined.